# StartCoroutine function not working on android, but working in Unity and Mac

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to curve the text in an `InputField` in a Unity scene using the below code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using TMPro;

public class TextWarper : MonoBehaviour
{

    private TMP_Text m_TextComponent;

    public AnimationCurve VertexCurve = new AnimationCurve(new Keyframe(0, 0), new Keyframe(0.25f, 2.0f), new Keyframe(0.5f, 0), new Keyframe(0.75f, 2.0f), new Keyframe(1, 0f));
    public float AngleMultiplier = 1.0f;
    public float SpeedMultiplier = 1.0f;
    public float CurveScale = 1.0f;

    void Awake()
    {
        m_TextComponent = gameObject.GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
    }


    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(WarpText());
    }


    private AnimationCurve CopyAnimationCurve(AnimationCurve curve)
    {
        AnimationCurve newCurve = new AnimationCurve();

        newCurve.keys = curve.keys;

        return newCurve;
    }

    IEnumerator WarpText()
    {

        VertexCurve.preWrapMode = WrapMode.Clamp;
        VertexCurve.postWrapMode = WrapMode.Clamp;

        //Mesh mesh = m_TextComponent.textInfo.meshInfo[0].mesh;

        Vector3[] vertices;
        Matrix4x4 matrix;

        m_TextComponent.havePropertiesChanged = true; // Need to force the TextMeshPro Object to be updated.
        CurveScale *= 10;
        float old_CurveScale = CurveScale;
        AnimationCurve old_curve = CopyAnimationCurve(VertexCurve);

        while (true)
        {
            if (!m_TextComponent.havePropertiesChanged && old_CurveScale == CurveScale && old_curve.keys[1].value == VertexCurve.keys[1].value)
            {
                yield return null;
                continue;
            }

            old_CurveScale = CurveScale;
            old_curve = CopyAnimationCurve(VertexCurve);

            m_TextComponent.ForceMeshUpdate(); // Generate the mesh and populate the textInfo with data we can use and manipulate.

            TMP_TextInfo textInfo = m_TextComponent.textInfo;
            int characterCount = textInfo.characterCount;


            if (characterCount == 0) continue;

            //vertices = textInfo.meshInfo[0].vertices;
            //int lastVertexIndex = textInfo.characterInfo[characterCount - 1].vertexIndex;

            float boundsMinX = m_TextComponent.bounds.min.x;  //textInfo.meshInfo[0].mesh.bounds.min.x;
            float boundsMaxX = m_TextComponent.bounds.max.x;  //textInfo.meshInfo[0].mesh.bounds.max.x;



            for (int i = 0; i < characterCount; i++)
            {
                if (!textInfo.characterInfo[i].isVisible)
                    continue;

                int vertexIndex = textInfo.characterInfo[i].vertexIndex;

                // Get the index of the mesh used by this character.
                int materialIndex = textInfo.characterInfo[i].materialReferenceIndex;

                vertices = textInfo.meshInfo[materialIndex].vertices;

                // Compute the baseline mid point for each character
                Vector3 offsetToMidBaseline = new Vector2((vertices[vertexIndex + 0].x + vertices[vertexIndex + 2].x) / 2, textInfo.characterInfo[i].baseLine);
                //float offsetY = VertexCurve.Evaluate((float)i / characterCount + loopCount / 50f); // Random.Range(-0.25f, 0.25f);

                // Apply offset to adjust our pivot point.
                vertices[vertexIndex + 0] += -offsetToMidBaseline;
                vertices[vertexIndex + 1] += -offsetToMidBaseline;
                vertices[vertexIndex + 2] += -offsetToMidBaseline;
                vertices[vertexIndex + 3] += -offsetToMidBaseline;

                // Compute the angle of rotation for each character based on the animation curve
                float x0 = (offsetToMidBaseline.x - boundsMinX) / (boundsMaxX - boundsMinX); // Character's position relative to the bounds of the mesh.
                float x1 = x0 + 0.0001f;
                float y0 = VertexCurve.Evaluate(x0) * CurveScale;
                float y1 = VertexCurve.Evaluate(x1) * CurveScale;

                Vector3 horizontal = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
                //Vector3 normal = new Vector3(-(y1 - y0), (x1 * (boundsMaxX - boundsMinX) + boundsMinX) - offsetToMidBaseline.x, 0);
                Vector3 tangent = new Vector3(x1 * (boundsMaxX - boundsMinX) + boundsMinX, y1) - new Vector3(offsetToMidBaseline.x, y0);

                float dot = Mathf.Acos(Vector3.Dot(horizontal, tangent.normalized)) * 57.2957795f;
                Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross(horizontal, tangent);
                float angle = cross.z > 0 ? dot : 360 - dot;

                matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0, y0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle), Vector3.one);

                vertices[vertexIndex + 0] = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertices[vertexIndex + 0]);
                vertices[vertexIndex + 1] = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertices[vertexIndex + 1]);
                vertices[vertexIndex + 2] = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertices[vertexIndex + 2]);
                vertices[vertexIndex + 3] = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(vertices[vertexIndex + 3]);

                vertices[vertexIndex + 0] += offsetToMidBaseline;
                vertices[vertexIndex + 1] += offsetToMidBaseline;
                vertices[vertexIndex + 2] += offsetToMidBaseline;
                vertices[vertexIndex + 3] += offsetToMidBaseline;
            }


            // Upload the mesh with the revised information
            m_TextComponent.UpdateVertexData();

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.025f);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is working fine in these cases

1. Always works in Unity editor and Mac
2. Works when used with a simple Text instead of an InputField on both Unity and Android
3. On Android it also works, when I call another function on the text, say making it bold or italic on Android after I have finished typing.

I am not able to understand why it works in these cases but as I am typing the text in the Input field on the Android device it doesn't work (but does in Unity and Mac in the same situation). There is a similar question on the site but I think it addresses a different issue. Can someone give any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: The formating for input and display can operate differently, or even use entirely different code. It could well be that the makers of Android decided that no transforms should apply while inputting stuff. Really, it is a rather sensible idea - inputting on a mobile device is already hard enough. No point making it any harder by making the text hard to read.

Comment: When you say "Mac", do you mean osX or iOS?

Comment: @Immersive osX, haven't tried it on iOS